# I am trying to convert an object type column to float. Not working

Tags: python, thomson-reuters-eikon, refinitiv-eikon-api

```
TSRdfr["Return"] = pd.to_numeric(TSRdfr.Return, errors='coerce')
```

This is not converting the data type of `Return` from Object to `float64`. I tried removing `errors ='coerce'` to see what's happening.

I am getting an error saying:

> Unable to parse NaN at position 0

when I dont use `errors = 'coerce'`.

The Return numbers are accessed from Refinitiv Eikon API. I am assuming they are too large to convert to `float64`. Any suggestions??

Comment: Could you provide more info about `TSRdfr`? What is content of it?

Comment: @bubble   I have a dataframe TSRdfr which I have accessed from Eikon API on Python.

Index Instrument Total Return

1.        RIO.L.          15.990065

2.        AAP.A.         22.543209

and so on ....

Comment: Total Return is of the type Object

Comment: I have a dataframe TSRdfr which I have accessed from Eikon API on Python.

Index Instrument Total Return

1.        RIO.L.          15.990065

2.        AAP.A.         22.543209

and so on ....

The data type of Total Return is Object which I need to convert to float64. I am using the syntax below.

TSRdfr["Total Return"] = pd.to_numeric(TSRdfr["Total Return"], errors='coerce')

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
import pandas as pd
import re
repat = re.compile('\d+(?:\.\d+)?')

# sample data frame 
df = pd.DataFrame({'Return': ['some data 123.123', 'tick 0.12']})

df.loc[:, 'Converted'] = df.Return.apply(lambda x: float(repat.findall(x)[0]))
```

Hope that helps

Comment: import re
repat = re.compile('\d+(?:\.\d+)?')
TSR_df_06_09.loc[:, 'Converted'] = TSR_df_06_09.Return.apply(lambda x: float(repat.findall(x)[0]))

Comment: AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'Return'

Comment: This means that `TSR_df_06_09` hasn't column named `Return`. What are column names of `TSR_df_06_09`; print `TSR_df_06_09.columns` to see all columns of the data frame.

Answer (score 0):

If your number is too large you can use the decimal library

```
import decimal
decimal.getcontext().prec = 100
df[col] = df[col].map(lambda x: decimal.Decimal(x))
```

Comment: import decimal
decimal.getcontext().prec = 100
TSR_df_06_09['Total Return'] = pd.to_numeric(TSR_df_06_09['Total Return'].map(lambda x: decimal.Decimal(x)))

Comment: Tried the above code.. getting this error: InvalidOperation: [<class 'decimal.ConversionSyntax'>]